# Am writing a code which could allow user to write a single variable function and the value for which it is to be calculated

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

```
Sub CatMain

t = (InputBox("Enter The value at which it is calculated"))      'like 0.5 

Fun =(InputBox("Enter The Function"))              'like sin(t)

msgbox Fun            'message should be 0.4794255


End Sub
```

Comment: Please be clear with the expected output that you want. What you have is just a statement, not a question.

Comment: okay, I want user to enter the function and the value where it is to be evaluated , the expected inputs and outputs have been given in the code comments

Comment: Is this VBScript, or VBA?  (Or does it need to be a single source code that works equally well in both languages.)

Answer (score 1):

Here are two approaches for Excel VBA:

The first is straightforward and uses `Evaluate()`:

```
Sub CatMain1()
    Dim t As Double
    Dim Fun As String

    t = InputBox("Enter The value at which it is calculated")
    Fun = InputBox("Enter The Function")
    MsgBox Evaluate(Replace(Fun, "t", t))
End Sub
```

It works as expected on your sample input, but crashes if `Fun` is `tan(t)` since it then attempts to evaluate `"0.5an(0.5)"`. You could address this by only replacing `t` in `Fun` if `t` is wrapped in parentheses, but that then requires that e.g. the function `t^2 + 1` be entered as `(t)^2 + 1`, which is annoying.

For another approach, create 2 named cells `t` and `y`, then:

```
Sub CatMain2()
    Dim t As Double
    Dim Fun As String

    t = InputBox("Enter The value at which it is calculated")
    Fun = InputBox("Enter The Function")
    Range("y").Formula = "=" & Fun
    Range("t").Value = t
    MsgBox Range("y").Value
End Sub
```

This lets Excel do the parsing and evaluation, but requires that 2 cells be reserved for this purpose (they can be made hidden if you want) and requires that auto-calculation is enabled (which it is as a default).

Neither way is particularly robust, though I make heavy use of the second approach in some of my code. Error handling should always be used for such code.

For `VBScript`, only a modification of the first is possible:

```
Sub CatMain3()
    Dim t, Fun

    t = InputBox("Enter The value at which it is calculated")
    Fun = InputBox("Enter The Function")
    MsgBox Eval(Replace(Fun, "t", t))
End Sub
```

This is fine if you are just running this yourself as a personal script -- but you should be aware that [eval is evil](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2003/11/04/eval-is-evil-part-two/) when run on strings supplied by untrusted users.

Comment: Thankyou so much sir, the first one working well but with eval , and as per my understanding am using vbscript   ..... Is evaluate used for vba??

Comment: @You tagged it `excel-vba` as well. As you have discovered, you need to use `Eval()` (which is a VBScript function) rather than `Evaluate()` (which is a method of the Application object in Excel VBA). I added that as a third answer.

Comment: @PAWANPANDEY You should be aware that many programmers would resist the idea that an eval-based approach is "working well". In addition to not being very robust, it is potentially a major security risk. A better approach would be to write (or find) a full-fledged VBScript expression parser.